# Alarm manager and broadcaster receiver not working

Tags: android

My alarm manager class

public class PSMScheduler {

```
public static void setSchedule(Context context) {
    setSchedule(context,0,0,5);
    setSchedule(context, 18, 30, 0);
}

private static void setSchedule(Context context, int hour, int min, int sec) {

    // the request code distinguish different stress meter schedule instances
    int requestCode = hour * 10000 + min * 100 + sec;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, EMAAlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); //set pending intent to call EMAAlarmReceiver.

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, sec);

    if(calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    //set repeating alarm, and pass the pending intent,
    //so that the broadcast is sent everytime the alarm
    // is triggered
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
}

}
```

my broadcast receiver

```
public class EMAAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    startPSM(context);
}

private void startPSM(Context context) {
    Intent emaIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 
    emaIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(emaIntent);
}
}
```

MY main activity

```
public PSMScheduler scheduler = new PSMScheduler();
public EMAAlarmReceiver receiver = new EMAAlarmReceiver();
Ringtone r;
Vibrator v;
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    scheduler.setSchedule(this);
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working. I also have the receiver declared in the manifest. Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.